# How do I render a <article> with HtmlTextWriterAttribute?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web, web-applications, frontend

If I want to render a normal div, I normally do

```
_writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
```

I tried _writer.RenderBeginTag("MyTag"); as shown on https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f2a9a9ww(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2 however it does not work.

But how do I do `<article>` any new HTML5 tag?

My project is a C# web app btw.

Comment: What is "does not work"? Can you elaborate? Oh, by _writer.RenderBeginTag("MyTag") I presume you do mean _writer.RenderBeginTag("article")?

Comment: Yes, I just want to generate <article> and obviously close it with </article>. I can't figure out how to render <anything> </anything>. Div, Span, P, H1, etc works using _writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div) but I don't know how to render other html5 tags.

Comment: A quick webform that I whipped up has no problem with `writer.RenderBeginTag("article");
        writer.Write("Contents of TheArticle");
        writer.RenderEndTag();` or any other tag name that I put in there, so I don't know what goes wrong at your end. What does happen exactly?

Comment: Ok, I just tested it out. _writer.RenderBeginTag("article"); does work.